# LAN and WLAN router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, lan

I have a router which establishes a LAN network in the house(IP-range 192.186.1.X). Additionally this router has a WLAN which can be used to connect to all LAN-devices.

Now I have an additional WLAN router connected to the previously described LAN to distribute WLAN in another part of the house. This router's IP-range is 192.168.11.X.

I would like to access all devices, regardless from the access point.

```
(My special case: WLAN_AndroidPhone <-> LAN_TowerPC)
```

Comment: Any particular reason for not using the same addressing for both WLANs?

Comment: The WLAN router wouldnt let me change to 192.168.1.X because IP-adresses from WAN-side network address rage should not be used.
But you are right, I will try to change the 192.168.1.X to 192.168.11.X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your comment where you implied that you're using the WAN port, I can say you don't need to connect the second AP using it, but directly through the LAN port. This will allow you to use the same IP network for both WLAN, hence solving the issue.

For informational purposes, the said comments:

> Doezer: Any particular reason for not using the same addressing for both WLANs?
>
> groebsgr: The WLAN router wouldnt let me change to 192.168.1.X because IP-adresses from WAN-side network address rage should not be used. But you are right, I will try to change the 192.168.1.X to 192.168.11.X